# cURL error while trying to activate a license on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, curl

I am using a certain premium wordpress theme. I purchased their license from official providers and when I put the license key on the box, it says 'cURL error: connection timed out after 800 seconds'.

Now, I have contacted the theme developers and they suggested me the following solution:

1. Update PHP Version
2. Increase PHP memory limit
3. Increase cURL timeout limit
4. Ask your host if there is some limitation with wp-cron, or if loopback is disabled.

Overall, they asked me to follow this guide from generatepress documentation: https://docs.generatepress.com/article/curl-error-28-connection-timed-out/

My problem is that, I am stuck at increasing cURL timeout limit. I have followed every step provided in the documentation that generatepress team told me to follow but I cannot find any option inside my cpanel that says increase cURL limit. Or, is it done via adding any sorts of codes? Let me know because I am a noob at coding. I followed every tutorial available on Google and YouTube but they didn't help. Looking for a possible solution from expert developers who can explain the problem to me as they would explain it to a 7 years old kid.

This is the [site](https://aim4slam.com/tekken-3-apk/)/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution to this I found after contacting the Generatepress team is that there was a firewall program implemented from the web hosting company that was preventing me to connect to GP server to activate the license. Once I contacted the hosting support, they disabled the feature and made some slight changes to my hosting account so that I was able to connect to the GP premium license.

Moreover, I also found that if the license has exceeded the number of allowed limits, it fails to connect, which was not the reason in my case.